# Python setup.py - force updating of requirement (using dependency_link)

Tags: python, versioning, packaging, setuptools

Say I have a python project named `myproject`, that depends on `mydependency`. Both are maintained by me.

**How can I make a setup.py for `myproject` so that it always tries to install a new version of `mydependency`, regardless of the one installed?**

Say I have a setup.py for a project with

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['mydependency'],
    dependency_links = ['url_to_mydependecy_repo@develop#egg=mydependency'],
    ....
)
```

The problem is that, on the second time the installation runs, `mydependency` will already be installed, so the installation will not fetch the repo and try to install a newer version. Since `mydependecy` is being actively developed (by me), I need `myproject`'s installation to always fetch the dependency link.

I've tried using `#egg=mydependency-dev` for the dependency_link and `'mydependency==dev'` in `install_requires`, with `version='dev'` on the setup.py of mydepency, but on the second installation 'dev' is already present, so it doesn't get fetched again.

Using a requirements.txt for `myproject`, with the same content of `dependency_links`, does exactly the same. On the following installations, the requirement is already met, so it won't be fetched again.

Note: using `pip -r requirements.txt --upgrade` does what I want, but I'm not installing manually, but from Openshift, so I can't really add `--upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Try to link `myproject` dependencies to dev-version of `mydependency` as you've tried already, but use a "valid" ([semver](http://semver.org/)?) versioning within your `mydependency` repo (i. e. not set version to `dev`). This will cause redownloading and reinstalling of a dependency (this works in my case, at least):

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['mydependency == dev'],
    dependency_links = ['url_to_mydependecy_repo@develop#egg=mydependency-dev'],
    ....
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing that makes it always clone the repo, but the installation stops at some point, because something like '0.1.dev1234567' does not match `'mydependency==dev'` :/

Comment: @jpimentel doest it really stop? In my case I see this message, but installing process continues

Comment: It seems like it installs `mydependency`, but doesn't check or install `mydependency`'s dependencies, so it's close but not there yet...

Comment: Probably you can do same trick with dependencies of `mydependency` :)